# Magento get/call for a specifc part of the admin menu

Tags: magento

Does anybody know how i can get the content of the "System" menu in the admin section.

[image]

I want to create a separate bar with the content of the system menu but i don't know how can i get it.

I tried this one, but it displays the entire menu. I want only the system part.

```
<?php echo $this->getMenuLevel($this->getMenuArray()); ?>
```

If you got any ideas, please suggest some hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be done not the phtml level but you should [create a module for it](http://codegento.com/2011/02/adding-a-new-admin-menu-item/). The first one takes a bit of time, but once you get the hang of it, it should be easy. The link should explain how.